# Using JAX-RS and trying to DELETE an item

Tags: client, jax-rs

I am currently working in Enterprise Java and I'm a newbie. I am trying to create a method which should delete a selected item from a data table. My project contains Graphical User Interface elements from  "http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/".

The deletion is made through a web-service.

This is the method I created so far:

```
public boolean delete(String articleId) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target
                = client.target(DELETE_URL);//this is a String

        //TODO call ws method delete
        try{
            target.request()....;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Delete Article Error ", ex);
        }
         return true;
    }
```

Could you tell me how can I handle the deletion in an appropiate way?

All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the following should do the trick.

```
target.request().delete(Response.class)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but shouldn't the articleId reference be somehow within that instruction? How will be known which article is to be deleted?

Comment: I was under the impression that the DELETE_URL contained the full references to the resource (with identifier). What does the webservice expect to get when calling the DELETE on the resource? It should be a matter of calling the correct URL (perhaps with specific response body).

Comment: Hi, I have changed the DELETE_URL. Thanks for help

Comment: If the above answer is a solution to your question please mark it as correct :-)